# Area under any Physics graph

Tags: integration, calculus

What all aspects of a graph determine or are used to determine the area under a graph? How can a person tell exactly what the area under any graph in this world represents?

Comment: Y axis units multiplied by X axis units

Comment: Speed × time is distance by definition of speed. Now if speed is not same and changing, we can still assume that for a very small time interval $dt$, speed is same and the distance travelled in this small time is $v(t)dt$ where $v(t)$ tells what the speed at some time is. Now to get the total distance travelled we should add all these small distances, $v(t_0)dt+v(t_1)dt+...+v(t_n)dt$ where $t_n$ is the time the person reached the destination. The above sum can be interpreted as sum of areas of rectangles with sides $v(t)$ and dt. So, the area under this graph is just total distance travelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area under a curve is calculated using Riemann integration. The basic idea behind that is as follows: suppose we have the graph of a function $f$. To approximate its area, we could divide the region of $f$ into numerous small strips, each roughly being a rectangle of some height. Then we could add up the area of all these strips, thus approximating the area. Now, we keep on making the strip width thinner and thinner, so that the area approximation gets better and better. When the strip width $h\to \infty$, we get the exact area under the curve.